# How to draw oblique prism using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

How can I draw this kind of prism using TikZ? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

You tagged the post as `tikz-3d`, so this is another option, using 3d coordinates. It needs the Ti*k*Z libraries `perspective` to adjust the view and `calc` for an easy position of the top face w.r.t. the bottom one.

Something like this:

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,perspective}

\tikzset
{% some styles
   every node/.style={black,fill opacity=1},
   axis/.style={black,thick,-latex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,white,
                    isometric view,rotate around z=180]
% COORDINATES
% bottom face
\coordinate (C1) at (0,0.7,0);
\coordinate (D1) at (1.2,0,0);
\coordinate (A1) at ($(D1)+(25:1.6)$);
\coordinate (B1) at ($(A1)+(135:2)$);
% vector A1A2=B1B2=...
\coordinate (V)  at (-0.7,0.5,3);
% top face
\foreach\i in {A,B,C,D}
   \coordinate (\i2) at ($(\i1)+(V)$);
% AXES (remove them if you want)
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[left] {$x$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[right]{$y$};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[above]{$z$};
% PRISM
% visible lines and color
\foreach\i in {1,2}
   \draw[fill=magenta,fill opacity=0.5]
      (A1) node[left]  {$A$}  -- (A2) node[left]   {$A'$} -- (D2) node[above] {$D'$} --
      (C2) node[above] {$C'$} -- (B2) node[right]  {$B'$} -- (B1) node[right] {$B$}  -- cycle;
\draw (A2) -- (B2);
% non-visible lines
\draw[dashed,white] (A1) -- (D1) node[below right] {$D$}  -- (C1) node[right] {$C$}  -- (B1);
\foreach\i in {C,D}
   \draw[dashed,white] (\i1) -- (\i2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After some tinkering, I come out with this:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) -- (0,0.5) edge (0,2.5) -- (1,0) coordinate(BR);
    \draw (-1,0) coordinate(BL)  rectangle (1,2) coordinate(TR)
    -- (0,2.5) coordinate(T) -- (-1,2) coordinate(TL);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0) -- (-0.5,0.4) -- (0.5,0.5) edge (0.5,2.5) -- (1,0);
    \draw [dashed] (-0.5, 2.4) -- (-0.5,0.4);
    \draw (-1,0)  rectangle (1,2) -- (0.5,2.5) -- (-0.5, 2.4) -- (-1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw  [dashed] (-1,0) -- (-0.5,0.4) -- (0.5,0.5) edge (0.8,2.5) -- (1,0);
    \draw [dashed] (-0.2, 2.4) -- (-0.5,0.4);
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1, 0) -- (1.3, 2) -- (0.8,2.5) -- (-0.2, 2.4) -- (-0.7,2) -- (1.3, 2);
    \draw (-0.7, 2) -- (-1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which looks just fine:

[image]